# How to build a "blog like" structure with pouchdb

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm not sure what would be the best approach for a blog like database structure in pouchdb. I'm working with ionic.

In a regular sql database I would have a ***categories table*** and an ***entries table*** each with and unique `id` field and `indexes` for things like "*categorie*" on the ***entries table***.

Since pouchdb doesn't have `tables`, should I use a pouchdb Database as an table equivalent?

Is there a better approach to this? One thing to mark is that categories can also be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a field in a document in a database that is unique, like "blog_category": "Horses" and use that to create a list of blog entries that match that. CouchDB is efficient at that.

Take a look at: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-quick-search and other plugins available here: https://pouchdb.com/external.html that might make this easy for you.

Here's another good link with info on pagination of results: https://pouchdb.com/2014/04/14/pagination-strategies-with-pouchdb.html